# LSTM Regression issues with masking and intuition (keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, lstm

I am using this architecture (a Masking Layer for varying trajectory lengths that are padded with 0s to maximum length trajectory followed by a LSTM with a dense layer afterwards that outputs 2 values) to build a regressor that predicts 2 values based on a trajectory.

```
samples, timesteps, features = x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features), name="mask"))
model.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True, name="lstm1"))
model.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=False, name="lstm2"))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', name="dense1"))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', name="dense2"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear', name="output"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
```

training with:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32)
```

My input data are of shape:

```
x_train (269, 527, 11) (269 trajectories of 527 timesteps of 11 features)
y_train (269, 2) (these 269 trajectories have 2 target values)
x_test (30, 527, 11) (--- same ---)
y_test (30, 2) (--- same ---)
```

I've preprocessed my data so as all my sequences have fixed length and smaller ones are filled with 0's at missing timesteps.
Thus, I'm using a Masking layer to skip these timesteps as they provide no information.

As expected, the output is of shape:

```
(30, 2)
```

But looking into it seems like its regressing the same values.

```
[[37.48257     0.7025466 ]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48257     0.70254654]
 [37.48257     0.7025466 ]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.7025465 ]
 [42.243515    0.6581909 ]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48257     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48261     0.7025462 ]
 [37.48257     0.7025466 ]
 [37.482582    0.70254654]
 [37.482567    0.70254654]
 [37.48257     0.7025466 ]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48257     0.7025466 ]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.482567    0.7025465 ]
 [37.48261     0.7025462 ]
 [37.482574    0.7025466 ]
 [37.48261     0.7025462 ]
 [37.48261     0.70254624]
 [37.48258     0.70254654]
 [37.48261     0.7025462 ]]
```

while my target values (y_test) is this:

```
[[70.   0.6]
 [40.   0.6]
 [ 6.   0.6]
 [94.   0.7]
 [50.   0.6]
 [60.   0.6]
 [16.   0.6]
 [76.   0.9]
 [92.   0.6]
 [32.   0.8]
 [22.   0.7]
 [70.   0.7]
 [36.   1. ]
 [64.   0.7]
 [ 0.   0.9]
 [82.   0.9]
 [38.   0.6]
 [54.   0.8]
 [28.   0.8]
 [62.   0.7]
 [12.   0.6]
 [72.   0.8]
 [66.   0.8]
 [ 2.   1. ]
 [98.   1. ]
 [20.   0.8]
 [82.   1. ]
 [38.   1. ]
 [68.   0.6]
 [62.   1. ]]
```

It's like approaching the whole dataset as 1 data point.
Can anybody with some experience find any obvious mistake here?

Appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: 9-th output sample is stand out, could you inspect, what is different with it's input, may be, short trajectory?

Comment: all trajectories have the same length as I've pre-padded them when preprocessing and loading the dataset. so length-wise its the same. Data wise, I'm not exactly sure but I think leaving it for more epochs it would make all values the same.

Comment: What was 9-th sample length before alignment padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When weights are random, they contribute to concrete inpute calculations chaotically, and we always get nearly same output.
Did you train the model? Looks like not, consider simple MNIST solver output before training:

```
[-2.39 -2.54 -2.23 -2.24 -2.29 -2.37 -2.39 -2.10 -2.34 -2.20]
[-2.28 -2.43 -2.25 -2.33 -2.28 -2.42 -2.26 -2.19 -2.37 -2.25]
[-2.43 -2.44 -2.25 -2.33 -2.33 -2.37 -2.30 -2.10 -2.37 -2.17]
[-2.33 -2.43 -2.28 -2.27 -2.34 -2.34 -2.28 -2.16 -2.37 -2.26]
```

and after:

```
 [-31.72 -31.65 -25.43 -20.04 -29.68  -0.00 -22.74 -25.88 -16.28 -13.30]  (5)
 [-12.44 -29.92 -21.19 -25.86 -22.53 -12.01  -0.00 -22.61 -18.88 -23.54]  (6)
 [-23.86 -25.77 -11.88  -9.18 -19.51 -20.85 -28.71  -0.00 -22.11 -14.57]  (7)
 [-33.67 -23.45 -17.82  -0.00 -28.89 -14.20 -32.54 -14.45 -11.13 -15.40]  (3)
```

---

UPD: So training is presented, but not accomplishes its target. Well, a lot of things can be a reason. Besides of technical issues, the task may be to complex for neural network, for example, if target function can't be learned with gradual improvement.

Check datapathes, try to simplify the task, find some example solution, that solves close problem, examine and rework it.

Comment: Thanks for your respone, I think I'm getting what you saying. I'm trying to approach it as a concrete architecture so backward propagating through the whole thing to make it learn. What you were saying is about training the LSTM prior to what I do now? I'm training using this command.     model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32) Also I've made some changes to the architecture, I'm editing original post now in a minute.

Comment: Also, I don't know what is this MNIST solver, I know of MNIST datasets... :P

Comment: Hm, as you applied `fit` you traine the model, but something is broken, so model still behave chaotically. I name `MNIST solver` the model trained on said MNIST dataset.